# Get copy of an object that won't change its parent object value

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object class `TimeDuration`. When I tried to change the value of object taken from the array Span, the value inside the array also changes. How can I get copy of an object that won't change its parent object value? I need to pass this copy to another function where I have to make changes to this object

```
 public void test()
        {
            List<TimeDuration> Span = new List<TimeDuration>();
            TimeDuration ob = new TimeDuration();
            ob.FromTime = DateTime.Now;
            ob.ToTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            Span.Add(ob);

           //Trying to assign value here!
           TimeDuration ob2= Span[1];
           ob2.FromTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);

        }

public class TimeDuration
    {
        public DateTime FromTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime ToTime { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Either turn it into a `struct`, make it immutable, or create a cloning method for it (and be vigilant about using it).

Comment: what happens `Subin` if you were to use the `new` key word to create and or store the object does it persist ?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair How can do this cloning method?

Comment: `Sublin` you can and should use what @Jon Skeet has provided and or suggested.. he's very `knowledgeable not to mention 100% on point with his anwsers`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you should *understand* why the current code behaves as it does. See [my article on reference types and value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) for more details.

> How can I get copy of an object that won't change its parent object value?

Two simple options:

- Create some sort of cloning method which creates a copy of the existing object. You need to do this explicitly - although you could use `object.MemberwiseClone` as a shortcut in some cases. In many cases it's pretty simple, although inheritance makes it harder.
- Make your `TimeDuration` class immutable, e.g. with methods of `WithToTime` returning
  a *new* version:

  ```
  public TimeDuration WithFromTime(DateTime newFromTime)
  {
      return new TimeDuration(newFromTime, ToTime);
  }
  ```

  You'd make your properties read-only, and provide a constructor taking both values (which can also validate them). You might even *consider* making it a struct at this point.

Comment: Really, I have an object with 4 property values. I want to change the value of one property of the object and pass this to another method. However, when I do that my parent object loss its property. Will Using a struct  solve the problem ?

Comment: @SubinJacob: This is why it's important to give a representative example in your question... You shouldn't (IMO) create a mutable struct. But you could still use either of the suggestions in my answer. Immutable types (whether classes or structs) are much easier to reason about than mutable ones.

Comment: After changing to struct I'm getting this error..Error 1 Cannot modify the return value of 'ProductionBL.Stage.StageSpan' because it is not a variable C:\Users\Subin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ProductionScheduling\ProductionBL\ArrangmentBL.cs 32 45 ProductionBL

Comment: @SubinJacob: I didn't say to *just* make it a struct. That was not one of the options I suggested. I suggested that *after* making it immutable you might want to make it a struct.

Comment: @SubinJacob: Why have you asked another question? There's no need for that. Fundamentally, I'd answer it in *exactly the same way as I have done here*. Do you understand why this is happening, and my suggested alternatives?

Comment: no I didn't. I even don't know why did it design so? why don't they gave a simple method that will create new instances with this value. why do I need to create clone for each. actually I have object going inside inside of other objects.

Comment: @SubinJacob: It sounds like you should take a step back from your current project, and study the *fundamentals* of C# - in particular value types and reference types.

Comment: I can't step back. I wrote the complete logic for my scheduling app and everything would work fine if I didn't face this.

Comment: @SubinJacob: No, I'm encouraging you to walk before you can run. If you've written a significant amount of code without understanding the fundamentals of C#, it's *very likely* that you've got bugs in your existing code. You can either keep running dangerously, accumulating more problems which will take a long time to find and fix, or you can take a breather, learn the basics, and then write better code. Obviously it's up to you, but I know which path I think is the better approach in the long term.

Comment: Thank you! I read your article about value type and ref type. And the analogy was nice. But if a class can't act as a value type. then actually whats happening when I make a clone. why its not recommended.

Comment: @SubinJacob: If you make the class immutable, it acts in a very similar way to a value type - certainly in terms of how you can use it. (String is a good example here.)

Comment: Decided to learn C# in depth and brought your book! Thank you

Comment: Is it a good idea to use pass by reference whenever it is possible?

Comment: @SubinJacob: Absolutely not. It makes the code much more confusing. Bear in mind that if you're using a class, you'll be passing *a* reference anyway - but by value. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: I read that article already. I was thinking of the performance while I asked so. Using reference would consume less memory and cycles, I thought.

Comment: @SubinJacob: I'm afraid that suggests you haven't understood what it means properly. When you pass a reference by value, why do you think that would be inefficient? It's *just* a reference. You're not copying a big object or anything.

Comment: No, I didn't mean so. And I understood it very well. Suppose I'm using struct instead of the class, and whenever I assigns it to a variable then its a copy (bit-bit copy). But when I assigns a class object it just assigns the address.In short- Isn't it inefficient to use value types where I could use reference type? I'm sorry if I'm repeating a blunder

Comment: @SubinJacob: If you're using a *large* struct, then yes, there's a *very slight* efficiency gain - at the cost of readability. Usually you shouldn't have large value types to start with though - it's rare for them to go over 16 bytes. As ever, you should concentrate on readability first and foremost - micro-optimization can come later. Only use `ref` when you actually *want* pass-by-reference behaviour, so that the method can change the value of the parameter and that change can be seen by the caller.

Comment: Then let it be like that, micro-optimization later. But considering the readability I have another problem. See this (http://pastie.org/7096908) code where I have ended up.Making a little research took me to chapter 6 of c# in depth. Am I in the right place?

Comment: @SubinJacob: That code looks *way* too deeply nested for my taste. It's hard to see what it's trying to do, but you should definitely try extracting some of the inner loops into separate methods. I'd also attempt to use `foreach` more than `for` loops - and the resetting of the counter looks odd to me. Without really knowing what it's meant to be doing, it's hard to know whether using an iterator block would help. Oh, and I'd follow normal .net conventions of making parameters camelCased. If you want more specific help with this, ask another question - it's miles off this question.

Comment: Ya I am posting it as another question. But didn't get why you prefered foreach loop instead of for loop. I felt for loop is more flexible and less resource hogging

Comment: @SubinJacob: Again on the micro-optimization at the cost of readability! Yes, `for` loops *can* be more flexible - if you really *need* to be able to access by index, or know the index for other reasons. But they're much clearer generally, and usually it's a bad sign for readability if you *do* change the index within the loop.

Comment: The question is here.please make edits to the question if required.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596994/reduce-nested-for-loops-and-if-statements-using-iterator-blocks

Comment: I got an answer http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24303/reduce-nested-for-loops-and-if-statements-using-iterator-blocks

Answer (score 1):

Consider turning the class into a struct, and of course also make it immutable:

```
public struct TimeDuration
{
    public DateTime FromTime { get; private set; }
    public DateTime ToTime { get; private set; }

    public TimeDuration(DateTime fromTime, DateTime toTime) : this()
    {
        FromTime = fromTime;
        ToTime = toTime;
    }

    public TimeDuration SetFromTime(DateTime fromTime)
    {
        var copy = this;
        copy.FromTime = fromTime;
        return copy;
    }

    public TimeDuration SetToTime(DateTime toTime)
    {
        var copy = this;
        copy.ToTime = toTime;
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your `TimeDuration` a `struct` instead of a `class`: value types are passed by value, so you will get a kind of "copy" behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are reference types.  The value inside the array is a pointer to the memory location of your `TimeDuration` object and not a new instance of it.  Therefore when you change the value it affects the array also.

You will have to create a new object of TimeDuration and pass that about.

Answer (score 0):

If you're always using `TimeDuration` this way, you may want to consider changing it from a `class` to a `struct`. To duplicate a `class`, you should implement [ICloneable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) and call the `Clone` method.