# Reduce nested for loops and if statements using Iterator Blocks?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to reduce this long nested for loops and if conditions to increase its readability and to optimize it for future reference.

While writing code for my scheduling app, I ended up with a method as shown below. Really, I have a data structure like [this](http://pastie.org/7097616). Here, I checks - Is there any stages (Inside LCycle) which using same Tool at same time and If its found so, another method `LCycleTimeShift` is called to make a rearrangment.

But I want to check whether the new arrangement is adaptable and the for loop counter is reset so that it will check the new arrangment again. I think this is not the better way to write the code for  better readabilty. A little research on the topic found that Enumerators can help me in this. But I don't know how can I accomplish this with the following code.

```
public List<LCycle> ToolArrangment(List<LCycle> TimeLineInit)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < TimeLineInit.Count; i++)//Each LIfeCycles In TimeLine
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < TimeLineInit[i].Stage.Count; j++)//Each Stages inTimeLine
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)//Each L esvd =ifeCycles Upto Current LifeCycle
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < TimeLineInit[k].Stage.Count; l++)//Each Stages of (LifeCycle upto current LifeCycle) 
                {
                    for (int m = 0; m < TimeLineInit[i].Stage[j].ToolList.Count; m++)//each tools in stage of timelkine
                    {
                        for (int n = 0; n < TimeLineInit[k].Stage[l].ToolList.Count;n++ )// Each tools In that stage (for loop outer of outer)
                        {
                            if (TimeLineInit[i].Stage[j].ToolList[m].ToolName == TimeLineInit[k].Stage[l].ToolList[n].ToolName)//If both tools are same (satidfying above for loop conditions)
                            {
                                if (IsTimeOverLaps(TimeLineInit[i].Stage[j].StageSpan, TimeLineInit[k].Stage[l].StageSpan))
                                {//tool using at same time.
                                    Stage ReplaceStage = TimeLineInit[i].Stage[j].DeepCopy();//Taking Copy of stage Span to make time shift
                                    Double TimeDifference=(ReplaceStage.StageSpan.ToTime-ReplaceStage.StageSpan.FromTime).TotalMinutes;//Calculating required time shift
                                    ReplaceStage.StageSpan.FromTime=TimeLineInit[k].Stage[l].StageSpan.ToTime;//FromTime changed accordingly
                                    ReplaceStage.StageSpan.ToTime=ReplaceStage.StageSpan.ToTime.AddMinutes(TimeDifference);//To Time Changed accordingly
                                    LCycleTimeShift(TimeLineInit[i], ReplaceStage);//passing refernce
                                    j = 0; k = 0; l = 0; m = 0; n = 0;//Counter Reset to validate the new arrangment
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return TimeLineInit;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to optimize your database. looping shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would suggest reading Code Complete. This code snippet violates just about every rule in the loop chapter. More than 3 nested loops should be refactored into separate methods and especially don't use single letter iteration counters with that many nested loops. No human can look at that code and easily understand what is happening.

Comment: @Despertar But somewhere I saw single letters are recommended for `for` loops

Comment: @SubinJacob Yes but only for VERY small loops or for small lambads in LINQ statements. If even a single nested loop is added you should change the loop counters to more meaningful names to avoid confusion between the two counters.

Comment: @Despertar Then,what about this line `j = 0; k = 0; l = 0; m = 0; n = 0;//Counter Reset to validate the new arrangment`. I know it must not be like that. But how can avoid that?

Comment: @SubinJacob in that case, using long counter names like `lifeCycleCounter`, `timeLinePerLifeCycleCounter` or a bit shorter like `stageCounter`

Comment: @Matten Ya,I will follow the naming as you suggested. Somewhere (really, I didn't remember from where) I saw its simple to use single characters to make the code simple and readable.

Comment: @SubinJacob "simple and readable" always depends on your loops :) For one or two nested loops, okay. But in your case you really should stick to self-commenting code, I mean self-describing names. With the refactoring possibilities this is an easy task in visual studio and can always be done if the complexity reaches a certain point.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Should I move my question?

Comment: @SubinJacob I'll speak for him and say yes :)

Comment: @antonijn delete and post or any way to move?

Comment: @SubinJacob I don't know, haven't had to move a question myself, so I suppose you could ask tim...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things before you start heading down that road.  Is the code working now?  Do you have unit tests?  I only ask because before starting on any refactoring, it is great if you have tests cases.

On the topic of enumerators, one line of code stands out to me:

```
LCycleTimeShift(TimeLineInit[i], ReplaceStage);//passing refernce
j = 0; k = 0; l = 0; m = 0; n = 0;//Counter Reset to validate the new arrangment
```

You are not allowed to modify a collection inside of an enumeration operation, so you might find that whatever magic you were doing inside that function that was working fine with for(...), it may no longer work with a foreach(...) or LINQ enumeration.  This is true only if it is deleting, adding items to the collection, which it appears to be doing.  I had to make some changes below since I assume the enumeration will change after each pass, this means I re-evaluate the duplicates each time.

As you said, it seems you want to find any two stages (not belonging to the same LCycle) that contain the same tool being used at the same time.  You then make some changes to the time for that stage and then modify the parent.  Makes sense to me.  This is what I have come up with.  I don't have any test cases, but maybe it gets you in the right direction.

```
var toolsInUse = TimeLineInit
                    .SelectMany(cycle => cycle.Stage
                    .SelectMany(stage => stage.ToolList.Select(tool => new
{
    Cycle = cycle,
    Stage = stage,
    Tool = tool.ToolName
})));

var duplicateUse = toolsInUse.Join(toolsInUse, 
                                    x => x.Tool, 
                                    x => x.Tool, 
                                    (a, b) => new { Use = a, Duplicate = b })
                                .Where(x => x.Use.Cycle != x.Duplicate.Cycle &&
                                            IsTimeOverLaps(x.Use.Stage.StageSpan, x.Duplicate.Stage.StageSpan));

while (duplicateUse.Count() > 0)
{
    var item = duplicateUse.First();

    Stage ReplaceStage = item.Use.Stage.DeepCopy();//Taking Copy of stage Span to make time shift
    Double TimeDifference = (ReplaceStage.StageSpan.ToTime - ReplaceStage.StageSpan.FromTime).TotalMinutes;//Calculating required time shift
    ReplaceStage.StageSpan.FromTime = item.Duplicate.Stage.StageSpan.ToTime;//FromTime changed accordingly
    ReplaceStage.StageSpan.ToTime = ReplaceStage.StageSpan.ToTime.AddMinutes(TimeDifference);//To Time Changed accordingly
    LCycleTimeShift(item.Use.Cycle, ReplaceStage);//passing refernce
}
```

I make no claims about performance, accuracy.  This is just to point you in a direction.  I hope it helps.

Comment: I hope my example is able to help you.

Comment: It helps . but your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try using LINQ , especially SelectMany and Join methods

```
var t = TimeLineInit
          .SelectMany(t=>t.Stage)
          .SelectMany(s=>s.ToolList);

... 

t
 .Join(t, [your conditions 1])
 .Join(t, [your conditions 2])
```

Comment: Can I use `IEnumerable` for this purpose?

Comment: All your lists are already IEnumerable. And you'll be using them when you use LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

The only reasonable option is to put the iteration stuff as methods inside your models that invokes each other, that way it'll be much more readable, and easier to understand.